# removing a certain element from a list in a dictionary's value

Tags: python, dictionary

not sure why i can't figure this out.  here is my dictionary:

```
begin = {'kim': ['a', 'c', 'nope'], 'tom': ['b', 'd', 'e', 'nope', 'nope']}
```

i'm trying to remove a specific element from the list in the dictionary's values.  the value i want to remove is 'nope'.  therefore, my desired output would be:

```
begin = {'kim': ['a', 'c'], 'tom': ['b', 'd', 'e']}
```

here is what i tried and it didn't seem to work

```
for i in begin:
    for a in begin.get(i):
        if a == 'nope':
            del a
print begin
```

any help would be greatly appreciated.  seems basic but just can't seem to get it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just filter out `nope`s from the lists, with list comprehension, like this

```
for key in begin:
    begin[key] = [item for item in begin[key] if item != 'nope']
```

Or you can completely recreate the `begin` dictionary, with dictionary comprehension like this

```
begin = {key:[item for item in begin[key] if item != 'nope'] for key in begin}
```

Comment: this is probably a little more pythonic than my solution (+1)

Comment: rly interesting - haven't had much experience using dictionary comprehensions haha

Answer (score 1):

```
for person in begin:
    while "nope" in begin[person]:
          begin[person].remove("nope")
```

Answer (score 1):

What you actually want is to remove the value *from a list* which happens to be inside a dictionary. You could think that `list.remove('nope')` may work, but it would remove only one 'nope' from each list. You may use either comprehension or `filter` function to filter out `nope`s For example:

```
# python 2.x - comprehension
new_dictionary = dict(
    (key, [v for v in value if v != 'nope'])
    for key, value in begin.iteritems()
)

# python 2.x - filter
new_dictionary = dict(
    (key, filter(lambda v: v != 'nope', value))
    for key, value in begin.iteritems()
)

# python 3.x - comprehension
new_dictionary = {
    key: [v for v in value if v != 'nope']
    for key, value in begin.items()
}

# python 3.x - filter
new_dictionary = {
    key: list(filter(lambda v: v != 'nope', value))
    for key, value in begin.items()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One line dict comprehension with filter:

```
>>> {k: filter(lambda s: s!='nope', v) for k, v in begin.items()}
{'kim': ['a', 'c'], 'tom': ['b', 'd', 'e']}
```